# Delete the spaces between items in Horizontal RecyclerView java

Tags: java, android

i have a small problem in RecyclerView when use it Horizontally, the problem in that there's a long spaces between items.

like this

item1 _________ item2  ___________  item3  ....

[image: image show the spacing between items]

what i want is to remove this space and then the items look like this :

item1 item2 item3

the RecyclerView  in my xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycleview1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

the custom view :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the java code in using in onCreate :

```
 recycleview1.setAdapter(new Recyclerview1Adapter(fontListmap));
            recycleview1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recycleview1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

can you help me solving this ??

Answer (score 3):

Change the following lines in your custom view to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/teal200"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is because every time a view is being inflated it is taking the height and width as match parent. Better would be to use custom values( 40dp 100dp etc) to get an idea about what is the width and height of each element in your custom view.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem bro, the spacing still exist

Comment: is the same brother, the same space !, is this woking for you ???

Comment: `recycleview1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));` delete this line and check

Comment: the color white between spacing gone, but still the distance exist Bro